# How to copy music from iOS5 device

Tags: ios

Besides running windows on virtual box, is there a native linux way to do this yet?

ifuse?

libimobiledevices?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, installing Rhythmbox should pull in everything you need.  The phone will appear as a media player in Rhythmbox; you can drag/drop whatever you like.

I do know that iOS support is sketchy because Apple tries their very best to obfuscate the platform.

Comment: well, I know that at one point I had everything working with iOS4 versions and had to install fuse and libimobile.... which are behind Rhythmbox and gtkpod etc... But now on iOS5 everything is broken and I'm only able to access the ipod in VM on Windows... I prefer Banshee but  will try Rhythmbox again when I get home. It's just been taking so long for all the rhythmbox plugins to port over to gtk3 and Rhythmbox has no visualisation for music.